# read .mbtiles files into leaflet.js

Tags: cordova, leaflet

we are building phonegap application where we want to put map using leaflet.js v 0.5
we try to read .mbtiles file through SQLitePlugin

https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

> function buildMap() {
>         var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("file:///sdcard/one_tile.mbtiles");
>         document.body.removeChild(msg);
>
> ```
>   var map = new L.Map('map', {
>       center: new L.LatLng(40.6681, -111.9364),
>       zoom: 11
>   });
>
>   var lyr = new L.TileLayer.MBTiles('', {maxZoom: 14, scheme: 'tms'}, db);
>
>   map.addLayer(lyr);
> }
> ```

but sqlitePlugin.openDatabase dosen't found the .mbtiles file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem . Had you checked this ? http://geospatialscott.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at florian fournier's Cordova plugin that reads MBTiles tiles out of the box : https://github.com/ffournier/cordova-plugin-mbtiles